Adding an insert_at() function to vector
I'm updating some (a lot) of old MFC code to replace CArray with vector.
There's one function that is a pain, and that is the insert function.  Where the existing code uses InsertAt() by array index, this now needs to use a vector iterator, and it annoys me no end!
It doesn't look so bad when it's just
array.insert(array.begin() + index, 10)
but when real code does...
class_instance->element_left.local_coordinate_point_array.insert(class_instance->element_left.local_coordinate_point_array.begin() + index, Point2(10,15));
It gets annoying pretty quick that you have to type everything twice, it makes the code far less readable, and if you make any changes, you have to make sure to change both, or you get unintended errors...and in most cases, offset is zero.  (I know it's not efficient to insert at the start of an array, but inserting is only done and non-performance critical times, and the time critical processing is iterating over the array, copying, binary searching, etc.)
I can create a template function, or even a macro that will allow
InsertAt(array, index, 10);
But that goes against the C++ syntax, and it would be nicer to keep it object oriented.
So, is there a good way to add an insert_at function to the vector template, so I can do
array.insert_at(index, 10)
Edit to add - There is a lot of code that deals with these arrays of 2D or 3D coordinates, and much of it is copying, transforming, creating/deleting.  Arrays are much faster than lists for most of this code, particularly with the ability to pre-allocate a large array, and then fill it with data.  There are just specific cases where I need to insert a new point at the start of the list, or at a specific location.

Create a helper function, standard library types are NOT designed to be inherited from. But if this is your normal use case why not use std::list? Or do you still need random access later?

Maybe you should have explained your use case better. Do you need to keep something sorted, do you need random Access etc. Do you want to replace one item?

Rewriting the old code to actually use iterators instead of indices may also be an option.

auto& theRef = class_instance->element_left->local_coordinate_point_array; theRef.insert(theRef.begin() + index, Point2(10,15));

There is nothing object-oriented in STL (and so in the STL-derived part of the C+- standard library---here, I said that, can ve move on?). Stepanov himself says so. Don't confuse object orientation with the variable.function() syntax. Just write InsertAt(array, index, 10). Nothing wrong with that whatsoever. A total no-brainer. Although I personally prefer insert_at.

You cannot add a member function to std::vector.
You can write a free function template (perfect forwarding omitted for the sake of brevity):
template<typename V,typename E> 
void InsertAt(V& vect,const E& elem,size_t index) {
      vect.insert(vect.begin()+index,elem);
}


But that goes against the C++ syntax

No. InsertAt(vec,42,42); is perfectly fine C++ syntax.

and it would be nicer to keep it object oriented

Free functions are considered part of the interface of a class. There is nothing anti-OO in writing this free function. To the contrary, adding any function as member would be not clean object oriented design.

Alternatively you can use a reference to avoid typing the same long name more than once:
auto& short_name = class_instance->element_left->local_coordinate_point_array;

And actually it looks like this deep nesting is the actual problem you should address. Frankly, I am a little confused that it is only inserting into a vector where this poses an issue.

This method is what I've gone with.  I don't like having to replace the OO member function syntax with a free out-of-class function, but it looks like the best that can be done.

@user1961169 one is not more OO than the other. Don't confuse syntax with design. You can do object orientation without any instant.method syntax


So, is there a good way to add an insert_at function to the vector template?..

There is a way but it may be not a good one.
namespace dev {
template<typename T>
class vector : public std::vector<T> {
public:
  iterator insert_at(size_t index, const T& value){ /* implement */}
};
// use dev::vector rather than std::vector everywhere in the project
// DO NOT use std::unique/shared_ptr<std::vector>/std::vector& no matter what

It may be useful when you need some specific extra functionality in many points of your project (say, for efficient interaction with some other library you use) but it's not a good idea in general. For example, our dev::vector::insert_at is slow - O(n) in size of the vector. Providing a convenient way to do this likely leads to other people using it more than they should. Also, declaring a pointer or reference to std::vector could lead to a very dangerous error as explained here.
Out-of-class function is generally better:
namespace dev {
template<typename T>
inline std::vector<T>::iterator InsertAt(std::vector<T>& vec, size_t pos, const T& value = T()){
  //implement
}
}
// later
ASSERT(class_instance != nullptr);
//...
ASSERT(class_instance->element_left != nullptr);
auto& coords = class_instance->element_left->local_coordinate_point_array;
dev::InsertAt(coords, index, 10);


insert_at is not worse in complexity than std::vector::insert. Adding the function will not make users write less efficient code than they can already write with std::vector

In my experience mere existence of a public function in our code base is seen as "it's OK to use it whenever, who has time to read those \warning doxygen tags" more often than I'd like. If you estimate that for your team it's different then sure, this particular issue is not a problem. Still, notice that STL itself uses the second option: a minimalistic (kinda...) class interface and algorithms implemented as out-of-class functions.

I think I understand your argument, but it is misplaced here. std::vector does have a method already that does exactly the same with same complexity. As OP writes already in their quesiton, they are merely looking for a shorter way to write array.insert(array.begin() + index, 10). So "it's OK to use it"? Sure why not. Its in the standard.
